# In C# is it possible to evaluate if a variable is different of null without using an operator?

Tags: c#, null, if-statement

For instance is it possible to write this

if (variable != null)

without using the operator != or == ?

Comment: Do you need this for anything specific, or just curiosity..?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, I'd just use `==` (if you are trying to avoid a custom equality operator, perhaps cast to `object` - it will be a nop cast anyway)

Other than than, my money would go with `object.ReferenceEquals(obj, null)`, but you could also use `object.Equals(obj, null)` since it handles `null` etc.

For completeness: why would I just use `==` / `!=` ? Simple: the compiler can do this *directly*. The IL for a null-check against an object is actually:

- load the ref
- branch if true (or branch if false)

That's it. Two IL instructions. It doesn't even do a "load null, equality check" - since the definition of "true" is "anything that isn't 0/null", and "false" is "0/null".

For something like `ReferenceEquals`, that is:

- load the ref
- load the null
- call the method
- (which creates a stackframe)
- load the first arg
- load the second arg
- do an equality check
- (then passes the value back down the stack frame returning true/false)
- branch if true (or branch if false)

I know which I prefer...

Comment: Marc, how do you know that? How do you know how much IL instructions is a C# statement? How can I learn it too?

Comment: @Dran : Reflector. Plus I'm currently doing lots of meta-programming, so writing IL directly.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`object.ReferenceEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx)`(variable, null)`.

Comment: ... or by creating an extension method and calling it like `obj.IsNotNull()`

Answer (score 2):

Call ToString() on it, if you get a System.NullReferenceException it was null.  :-)

But why?

Answer (score 2):

You could really be a jerk and use:

```
if (x is object) {
    // not null
}
else {
    // null
}
```

Comment: I didn't know `is` gave false for null. Thanks. Not that I'll use this code anywhere :)

Answer (score 1):

How would you check if something is null if you do not want to use an operator ?
What's the reason for this question anyway ?

Comment: With a static method ? Staticclass.IsNull(variable)
I would like to check if it's possible to write code without using operators.

Comment: @Dran - but **why** do you want to write code without operators? Operators are (especially in this case) *faster*.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only other syntax that fits your description is to use the ?? operator, (which is still an operator, i gues...) but it either returns the value, or if the value is null, it returns the next expressions value as in

```
 string nullStr = null;
 string out1 = nullStr?? "NullString";    // out1 = "NullString";
// ------------------------------------------------------------
 string realStr = "RealString";
 string out2 = realStr ?? "NullString";   // out2 = "RealString";
```